# Css clip image with box-shadow does not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to `clip` an image. This image has a box-shadow property.

Want I want is to apply a `clip` to the image but I want to mantain the `box-shadow`, not to the original image but to the `clip` image.

How can I do that?

Follows my HTML/CSS3 code:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height 100px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  clip: rect(0px, 500px, 500px, 0px);
  transition: all 1s;
}

#image {
  position: relative;
}
#image:hover img {
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 50px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg">
</div>
```

*Note: I want to avoid using javascript or jquery to manage this problem. But of course, if there is no other solutions and the javascript/jquery code is necessery, I will use it.*

[EDIT]

I want that the original image and the final image have box-shadow, and the box shadow could be animated as well as the clip is.

Comment: add `:` `height:100px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution, no clip needed.

```css
#image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px; background:url("http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg");
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

#image:hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">

</div>
```

Comment: But the only point is to have the clip image and the box-shadow at the same time.

Comment: @RicardoRocha see my edit, you can try to use the image as a background.

Comment: It's better, but i want the original and final position of the image have box-shadow. This solution is still good enough for me.

Comment: I made a edit change to the post for better understanding what i really want